# How to printf something after the string in the same row in C FILE?

Tags: c, string, file

i have a problem printing something after the array for example:

```
while(fgets(row,MAX,f) != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s %d",row,upper_lett_in_curr_row(row));
    }
```

The integer value is the number of words with upper letters, that needs to appear next to the row string, but this value appears in the next row, why? It rare because when i write this code:

```
while(fgets(row,MAX,f) != NULL)
        {
            printf("%d %s",upper_lett_in_curr_row(row),row);
        }
```

It prints in the same row but on the start of the row, not in the end of the string.

Comment: May be your string `row` having '\n` next line character at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `fgets` to read from a file, it will read the whole line including `\n`. So while printing:-

```
 printf("%s %d",row,upper_lett_in_curr_row(row));
```

`row` string contains `\n` at the end. So after printing the string, due to `\n` at the end cursor will move to next line and print the integer.

To avoid this, you can do

```
int len;
// your stuff
while(fgets(row,MAX,f) != NULL)
{
    len = strlen(row);
    row[len-1] = '\0'; // make \n as null

    printf("%s %d",row,upper_lett_in_curr_row(row));
}
```

Comment: The `strlen()` function returns `size_t`, and you should move it inside the loop. And make it `const`. :)

Comment: This one helps. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @SkokajSkokaj If this answer solves your problem means validate it!

Answer (score 3):

```
fgets(row,MAX,f)
```

`\n` is a valid character to `fgets`, so the string that `fgets` fills (`row`) has the new line character at the end, you need to remove it manually.